# Inserting data into a junction table

Tags: php, sql, database-design, phpmyadmin, many-to-many

This is my current table design
[image]

I have a many to many relationship.

For example I created / inserted an entry to the musicians table how do I actually pass its primary key (id) that is generated from it and immediately insert it to field  musician_id from musician_x_instrument table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you use mysqli, you get if using the [insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) function:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
$mysqli->query($query);

printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
```

You then insert this ID in the join table as you would insert any other data into any other table.

Comment: I am using mysql, the old one

Comment: Then surprisingly, the function is called mysql_insert_id. http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php.

Comment: are there any more approach other than that?

Comment: You could also use the LAST_INSERT_ID() SQL function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html. How come I can find this in a minute using Google and you can't?